# how can I ask p7zip via CLI to batch zip directories into their respective compressed archives

Tags: p7zip

I've read several questions on this forum on how to do this but cannot find a way to do this via p7zip. I want to basically have p7zip go through a a directory and turn each top level directory in that directory into a zip or 7zip file. So for example I cd to directory a. I want directory b, c, d, e, etc to turn into their respective compressed files. I'm not an advanced user with the command line. I will get there, so bare with me in asking this question. p7zip by the way is a compression utility that does rar, zip and more through a command line interface.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux/Unix you still have to use tar in order to backup directories. p7zip is still just a file compressor:

tar cf - [directory a] | 7z a -si [filename].tar.7z

Comment: Actually it is not. I can do on m mac 7z a filename.7z path/to/directory. For example

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wakwcxpz7t8xpg6/output%20for%207z%2012-12-2016?dl=1


I've done this on a linux machine  running p7zip as well.

Comment: That's pretty special then since this is straight from from the p7zip documentation from the author:

Comment: On Linux/Unix, in order to backup directories you must use tar !
   to backup a directory  : tar cf - directory | 7za a -si directory.tar.7z
   to restore your backup : 7za x -so directory.tar.7z | tar xf -

Comment: The author specifically warns against using the -r flag to recurse directories if you're making backups because it will not get all that hidden files and directories that begin with a dot. He specifically says you need to use tar.

Comment: I never wanted to back up directories. I'm zipping them or in this case trying to run a batch compression  to make uploading easier, or in some user's case downloading. So there must be away. As shown I did do this in my example. I did 7zip a directory, or in this case archive a directory using p7zip.